# Transient analysis initial conditions in book

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, transient

There is an example in Book:

[image]

[image]

Why is \$V_R = 5i_R\$? I can't see that.

more info:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: \$i_R\$ is not marked, but if it is the current through the 2 \$\Omega\$ resistor then \$v_R = 2 \Omega\cdot i_R\$.

Comment: We do not know the initial conditions, all names of the currents and voltages nor the intermediate results which are referenced in the text. We even do not know if there has been used an equivalent circuit where the problematic relation can well be true. You should include more stuff  to get something more than guesses - maybe a link to the full page in high resolution.

Comment: @user287001 more details added but it seems to be an error in text as "Vladimir Cravero" found